# Blocking Grammarly Icon - Javascript - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, grammarly

Does anyone know how to block GrammarlyGo icon in the text area and anywhere else with javascript? I am making a Chrome extension and need to place an icon in the same place that GrammarlyGo places their icon and therefore need to stop GrammarlyGo's icon from appearing.

[image]

The problem is it isn't always in appearance it only appears when there is active selected text especially amongst multiple lines. I have this code but it has no effect:

```
const elementToBlock = document.querySelector('[data-grammarly-part="cheetah-entry-button"]');
const hideElement = (element) => {
  element.style.display = "none";
};

const observerConfig = { childList: true, subtree: true };
const observerCallback = (mutationsList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0 && mutation.addedNodes[0] === elementToBlock) {
      hideElement(elementToBlock);
    }
  }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(observerCallback);
observer.observe(document.documentElement, observerConfig);
```